# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - explanation?

Tags: .net

I am looking for steps/guidance to troubleshoot the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and an explanation of why the issue occurs.

I am looking for a more general explanation, so if I get the error, what steps I should take to find the problem. I often see posts where someone provides a specific piece of code, and someone else will provide the fixed code (sometimes). If simple code examples are provided to illustrate this problem, that's fine.

I need a high level explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to explain it is that if your object reference (your variable) is `null`, then you can't access any properties or methods on it without triggering that exception. Here's an example of code that would throw a "Null Ref" exception (as they are called):

```
string s = null;
int leng = s.Length;
```

So I define a `string` as `null`, but then try to access its `Length` property. The exception occurs. If I had used a method on that `null` `string` like `ToString()`, the exception would happen as well.

The problem with tracing down this error is that, as you can see from the error text, you can't tell right away where the Null Ref has occurred. You'll have to put in a breakpoint before the exception occurs and walk the code until you find the offending piece.

Comment: Hi @Graham, thanks, this is helpful. Do you know of any good examples/tutorials of doing the breakpoints/debugging for this error? I do see Mike P left a link in a reply to another answer to this post which I will check out , but the more resources the better.

Comment: That link looks fine to me for a good overview of debugging. If you've always 'debugged' by just changing your code to print out variables to see their state, then you will LOOOOVE debugging in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There are no general steps - such problems typically lie in the logic of your code and vary too much to have "one size fits all" solution.

One of the things you could do though, is break into the debugger when this exception is thrown (turn-on [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) under DEBUG/Exceptions), look at which object is `null`, and try to figure out *why* it is so, by examining the objects, perhaps go up the call stack and see what the callers look like etc...

Comment: Based upon the question, I'd suggest adding a link to a general Visual Studio debugging tutorial such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Answer (score 0):

It means you have used an object that is currently null or not instantiated yet.

Thats the high level.... basically whatever is breaking likely contains a null value. Put a break point in a step through it and where its breaking is likely what is null.

Comment: An *object* can't be null - a *reference* is null. (That reference is probably the value of a variable.) It's important to distinguish between variables, objects, references etc - particularly when explaining concepts to relative newcomers to a language.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Object, and the Object reference is null, then calling a method or trying to access a property on that object will throw this error.  For example..

```
String myString = null;
string anotherString = myString.Substring(0,2); //this will throw an error.
```

Do you have some code as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Being an extremely common error, you will quickly learn how to deal with it. Basically what it means is that you are trying to use something that does not exist.

Here is an example:

```
    Dim lstNumbers As List(Of Integer)
    lstNumbers.Add(1)
    lstNumbers.Add(2)
    lstNumbers.Add(3)
```

When you go to run this code, it will give a null reference exception and provide you with the  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. What this means is that you created an object called 'lstNumbers' and told the compiler that it *will* be a list on integers, but you have not actually *created* the list. In essence, you created a placeholder, but no object to hold anything.

To fix it, you must create the object itself. So in the case of the example above, you would change it to:

```
    Dim lstNumbers As New List(Of Integer)
    lstNumbers.Add(1)
    lstNumbers.Add(2)
    lstNumbers.Add(3)
```

The `New` keyword tells it to create a new list object and assign it to that space. Now you can add to it without any errors. Some objects will initialize themselves such as strings, integers, and others.

So the best advice for troubleshooting these types of errors is to determine why the object is not set to an instance of itself. Check to make sure you have used either the New function or set it to an existing object, such as:

```
    Dim lstNumbers As New List(Of Integer)
    lstNumbers.Add(1)
    lstNumbers.Add(2)
    lstNumbers.Add(3)

    Dim lstNumbers2 As List(Of Integer)
    lstNumbers2 = lstNumbers
```

You don't need to use New on lstNumbers2 since you are assigning lstNumbers to it. However, if you tried the following, it wouldn't work because lstNumbers has not been initialized:

```
    Dim lstNumbers As List(Of Integer)

    Dim lstNumbers2 As List(Of Integer)
    lstNumbers2 = lstNumbers
```